# Crystal Reports : Bad Date format string error

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I am a newbie to crystal reports, I have a crystal report for which I have a data source from which I am using some fields on to the report.

Crsytal Report Name : InventoryReport

Data Source : I am giving Stored Procedure -- GetInventoryData

Fields :  ItemID, ShippedDate,  ItemName

I have to get all items which are shipped in between  FromData and ToDate of ShippedDate, so I am using formula   {GetInventoryData;1.ShippedDate} in {?FromDate} to {?ToDate}

dataType of Shipped Date is String and I have to convert to Date as it needs to be compared but I am having issues in that...

ShippedDate value will be : 2011-04-19 16:02:14.0000000

I have to convert at crystal reports side only..

Please help me how can I cast it to date

Comment: I think this [How to convert string value to proper datetime format][1] might help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545744/how-to-convert-string-value-to-proper-datetime-format

Answer (score 1):

actually even better don't use that formula .... in selection formula using the date range explained above

```
date(split({GetInventoryData;1.ShippedDate}," ")[1]) in {?daterange}
```

Comment: Protip: Using Crystal functions, like `split()`, in the record selection formula will cause that selection to happen on the client side versus the server side. That means all records regardless of date will be returned from the database which potentially translates into a large performance hit. For large datasets, it's best to use a SQL Expression in your DB's native syntax to do the data manipulations.

Comment: agree completely that an SQL Expression would be a much better solution if performance is effected by the suggested solution. I suppose I shy away from providing SQL examples because of syntax issues. an example in my SQL flavor if he is interested TO_DATE({fn LEFT(ShippedDate,10)},'YYYY-MM-DD') as cvtShipDate

Comment: In my case can't make any change in SQL Expression as I can't modify the stored procedure.. I can only do at crystal report side.. by the way please could you help me how to create daterange paramaeter I am totally new to crystal reports...

Comment: you can create your SQL expression in a crystal command expression. If you want to explore that let me know.  I can try to work through it with you or find some reference for you to view

Comment: @msbyuva Neither SQL Expressions nor SQL Commands require any changes to the DB; they simply give you more control over the query.

Comment: @CoSpringsGuy  please could you help me how to form the SQL Expression in crystal report.. any references would also be helpful.. thanks

Comment: here is a quick video I found that can get you started http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHNHsIUbcn8 You will need to know a little about your SQL syntax but there should be plenty of good reference for that. To convert your date you will need to see how your syntax handles things in comparison to the example I posted above to convert the string into a date

Answer (score 0):

If you are using string, you may do a simple less-than or greater than like:

```
...where ShippedDate >= '2011-04-19 00:00:00' and ShippedDate <= '2011-04-19 23:59:59'
```

this is like:

```
...where ShippedDate >= '<from-date> 00:00:00' and ShippedDate <= '<to-date> 23:59:59'
```

This would work and you'll not have to cast to a date.

You may also use as (If it works for you):

```
...where ShippedDate >= '<from-date>' and ShippedDate <= '<to-date>'
```

Comment: hi.. I have to convert at crystal reports side only..as I don't have access to modify the procedures... because they are being used in various other applications..

Answer (score 0):

one way ... create a formula called cvtDate

```
date(
tonumber(split({GetInventoryData;1.ShippedDate},"-")[1])
,
tonumber(split({GetInventoryData;1.ShippedDate},"-")[2])
,
tonumber(split({GetInventoryData;1.ShippedDate},"-")[3])
)
```

then instead of creating two date parameters.. create only one called daterange that allows range values under values options
Then selection formula would be

```
{@cvtDate} in {?daterange}
```