# How to filter dates older than 3 days in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I'm currently working a project that requires a report. I have never used any type of reporting before but I have researched and many people use Crystal Reports. I have implemented this into my project and and customized it pretty well. However, I am a bit stuck because I don't know how to do the next step. We deal with "deals" for cars. Once a deal is sent in, we keep track of it. These deals have what we call a "deal date" which is the date that deal was finished. What I need is a way to filter these deal dates to show up on this report. For example, if the deal date was yesterday (06/25/2013), I need this deal to show up on the report 3 days or more after that date. So if it is 06/28/2013 then that deal will show up on the Crystal Report. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this? Keep in mind that I have never used Crystal Reports before so I'm no exactly sure where to begin. I have searched to do something like this but have come up empty handed. Currently the Report views all the "deals" (which is thousands of rows) in the database. Any help is appreciated! Thank you! If anymore information is needed, please let me know!

Comment: how are the filers being done currently `SQL` if so just write a query that checks `BETWEEN FromDate ToDate`

Comment: Design your query to look between two dates and assign it to the newly created Crystal Report....

Comment: if you only want records in the last three days from when the report is run, then add a line in record selection like `{table.date} > currentdate-4`

Comment: If i have understand well you need something like forecast deal?

Comment: Currently there are no filters. It is just displaying every single record in the database. Wouldn't that query include everything within those date range? It needs to be 3 days or older past the "deal date."

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
      D1    D0    T
<--|--|--|--|--|--|-->
  -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0
```

- D0: a deal that occurred 2 days ago
- D1: a deal that occurred 4 days ago

Assuming:

- Want D1
- Don't want D0

Then:

Select Report | Selection Formulas | Record...

Enter the following formula:

```
(CurrentDate - {table.date_field}) > 3
```

To convert a string to a date, use this syntax:

```
( CurrentDate - DateValue({table.string_field}) ) > 3
```

Comment: I read the requirement that if more than 3 days have elapsed between today and the deal date, then include the records.

Comment: I have given the above a shot. I'm getting "A number is required here." and the {table.date_filed} is highlighted.

Comment: Is your field a date or date/time field?

Comment: It was a Varchar(50) but before posting this question changed it to just date. (We exported the data to a .csv file from another application and then imported that .csv file into Sql Server, was set up to varchar(50) just to make sure that it will import properly. After the data has been imported, it is now just a "date" field.

Comment: Did you try it with the parentheses?

Comment: I did not.. I will give it a shot at work in the morning! Thanks for all the help! I will let you know if it works!

Comment: I'm still getting an "A number is required here." at the {table.date_field} section. I have put (CurrentDate - {Vehicle.DealDate}) > 3.

Comment: Type:String and Length: 10. I assume that this would be incorrect. How do I change that field to the type date?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545744/how-to-convert-string-value-to-proper-datetime-format