# Advanced conversion of a single number to year, along with hyphen

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to convert the string value to datetime in crystal report

date format are

```
05-10-7-AAAA (mm-dd-year(2017)-AAAA)
05-23-3-00   (mm-dd-year(2013)-00)
...
```

My desired output is

```
10-May-2017
23-May-2013
...
```

My good reference has been [How to convert string value to proper datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545744/how-to-convert-string-value-to-proper-datetime-format) & the following attempts threw me errors:

```
Date({ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER}[4 to 5], ***{ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER}[1 to 2], {ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER}[7]***)  //Too many arguments have been given to this function
```

&

```
DateValue({ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER})  //Bad date format string
```

Thank you so much in advance and I will be as responsive as I can!

Comment: which region is that format?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Hi, thank you for your comment. Could you rephrase what you meant by 'region'?

Comment: can you post what errors you are getting?

Comment: @siva I have posted the error as a comment (right next to the code above).     1) //Too many arguments have been given to this function 2) //Bad date format string.

Comment: why did you gave `***{ORDERCHECKVIEW.LO` astrik in formula?

Comment: @siva the stackoverflow did it as I want the font to be bold/tilted

Comment: What part of the world uses that date format?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu USA, Specifically at the company that I work for

Comment: I see... now tell me how did you know that this 05-10-7-AAAA is 2017?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Basically 1~9 is 2011~2019 :) Please feel free to ask me any question. Sorry that I was not clear enough

Comment: if you have a data dated 2001-2009?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I don't count those years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Formula and apply the code below. {Command.mydate} will be replaced with your field

```
local StringVar mDate;
local StringVar mMonth;
local StringVar mDay;
local StringVar mYear;
//local StringVar mSuffix:= StrReverse(left(StrReverse({Command.mydate}),instr(StrReverse({Command.mydate}),"-",1)-1));    // to get suffix

mDate:= left({Command.mydate},InStrRev ({Command.mydate},"-" )-1);     // get dd
mMonth:= left(mDate,2);  // get MM
mDay := Mid (mDate,4 ,2 );  // get YYYY
mYear := totext(2010 + CDbl (right(mDate,InStr(StrReverse(left({Command.mydate},InStrRev ({Command.mydate},"-" )-1)),"-") -1 )),0,""); // transform   2017

cDate(cDbl(mYear),cDbl(mMonth),cDbl(mDay));   // this will display dd-MM-YYYY     may not display as 01 for dd but you can always customise this in the GUI the important point is this is now a date field
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!! It works like a charm! I really appreciate all your help. You have been the only one who has shown interest on my question. Thank you so much again and hope you have a great weekend!