# crystal report - if else statement when array is declared: string length error

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm a noob in Crystal Report.

I'm getting     `String length is less than 0 or not an integer` error.

on  `left({ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER},InStrRev ({ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER},"-" )-1)`

of the code below:

```
local StringVar mDate;
local StringVar mMonth;
local StringVar mDay;
local StringVar mYear;

if {ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER} =  'N/A'
then 'N/A'

else

mDate:= left({ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER},InStrRev ({ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER},"-" )-1);     
mMonth:= left(mDate,2);  
mDay := Mid (mDate,4 ,2 );  
mYear := totext(2010 + CDbl (right(mDate,InStr(StrReverse(left({ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER},InStrRev ({ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER},"-" )-1)),"-") -1 )),0,""); // transform   2017

cDate(cDbl(mYear),cDbl(mMonth),cDbl(mDay));  

    cDate(cDbl(mYear),cDbl(mMonth),cDbl(mDay));
```

Can anyone please explain what's wrong? I don't think my if-else statement is wrong..

FYI, I have previously asked a question and this question is a follow-up:
 ([Advanced conversion of a single number to year, along with hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143964/advanced-conversion-of-a-single-number-to-year-along-with-hyphen))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> compounded if-else

```
    local StringVar mDate;
    local StringVar mMonth;
    local StringVar mDay;
    local StringVar mYear;

    if {ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER} =  "N/A"
    then "N/A"

    else
    (
    mDate:= left({ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER},InStrRev ({ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER},"-" )-1);     
    mMonth:= left(mDate,2);  
    mDay := Mid (mDate,4 ,2 );  
    mYear := totext(2010 + CDbl (right(mDate,InStr(StrReverse(left({ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER},InStrRev ({ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER},"-" )-1)),"-") -1 )),0,""); // transform   2017

//      cDate(cDbl(mYear),cDbl(mMonth),cDbl(mDay));

ToText(cDate(cDbl(mYear),cDbl(mMonth),cDbl(mDay)),"MM/dd/yyyy") ;

    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much again! I'm actually getting an error for "else (....)", that a string is required here. If you could help me out on this once more, it'd be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: just see updated script. ... N/A should be cDate(1900,01,01)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and update. The filed prints out as 01-January-1900, while my desired outcome is "N/A" when the Lotnumber is "N/A". Sorry for too much question!

Comment: so I tried if {ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER} =  "N/A"
then {ORDERCHECKVIEW.LOTNUMBER}, but it gives me the same 'a string is required here' error.. I'm terribly sorry for bugging you

Comment: the only way to display "N/A" is converting the else cDate to string

Comment: Hands-down! You are awesome!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much for helping me twice in a row!! And very appreciated for your quick reply and updates. Hope you have an awesome day because you deserve it!