# substring function in crystal report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I try to convert the string(20220815) to date type. But the substring function return this

> Error: a number,currency amount,boolean ,date,time,date-time,string expected here

Comment: Does this link help at all?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545744/how-to-convert-string-value-to-proper-datetime-format

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I have found the solution thanks you